# apply solid background color to p tag

Tags: html, css, paragraph, margin

I have two p tags, like this:

```
<p class="under">Loxi phoxie</p>
<p class="over">Krinki Conxy</p>
```

I wan't the p.over to cover p.under, so I made this in the css:

```
margin: -22px 0 0 0;
background: #fff;
```

The p.over tag positions itself perfectly over p.under but the text of p.under shines through so its a mess of text. How can I achieve my goal, I wan't the p.over to cover p.under?

Ps. I can't hide any of the tags with javaScript or displey: none; Ds.

Comment: I wan't the p.over to cover p.under

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add to `p.over { position: relative; z-index: 2; }`

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y94Gm/)

[updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/y94Gm/1/)

Comment: That won't help. `p.under` will still be visible.

Comment: The key here is the background colour you added. It's the colour that masks the underlying element.

Comment: Glad I could help. Actually `position: relative` alone does the work, `z-index` is optional. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y94Gm/3/).